# Normality test - when my IV and DV are both continuous variable?

Tags: spss, normality-assumption

I know how to run the normality test when Your IV (e.g. Gender / Categorical Data) and DV (e.g. Exam Score / Continuous Data ). As mentioned in https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IiedOyglLn0

I would like to ask you, how about when my IV and DV are both continuous variable?

Comment: You need to specify exactly why you want to do this. If your notation implies you are going to do a regression then you almost certainly do not want to test either your predictor or outcome for normality.

Comment: Sir, thank you so much for your reply. I would like to run a correlation test. If the data is normally distributed, I could apply Pearson's or otherwise Spearman’s test .  Thank you so much if you could advice me.